# My turtle character leaves a visible trail whenever it moves

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to make a game with a monkey moving up and down, but whenever the monkey moves somewhere the monkey leaves behind a visible black line.

Here's my code:

```
import turtle

win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Monkey by Anders")
win.bgpic('Background.gif')
win.bgcolor("dark green")
win.setup(width=800, height=600)
win.tracer(0)
monkeyimg = 'Monkey.gif'
win.addshape(monkeyimg)
turtle.shape(monkeyimg)

#Speed
move_speed = 10
turn_speed = 10

#movement
def forward():
  turtle.forward(move_speed)


def backward():
  turtle.backward(move_speed)

#position
turtle.backward(325)
turtle.left(90)

#keyboard
win.onkey(forward, "Up")
win.onkey(backward, "Down")

#main game loop
while True:
    win.update()
    win.listen()
```

And here is the trail it leaves.

Visible black line from monkey:

[image]

Comment: The whole point of the turtle module is to draw lines. Why not use something like PyGame or the like for doing stuff like this?
Anyway, using `turtle.up()` before moving will hide the lines.

Comment: Thank you so much, and yeah i should probably use pygame instead i just thought that turtle would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `Turtle` objects in turtle graphics leave a trail. You can use the [`turtle.penup()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.penup) method, or the `turtle.pu()` method *or* the `turtle.up()` method *(they all do the exact same thing)* to lift the pen from the paper so that it doesn't leave a trail.

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding `penup()` as @LeMinaw suggests, your code is structured incorrectly.  You don't want to use `while True:` in an event-driven world like turtle.  Instead, consider:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

MONKEY_IMAGE = 'Monkey.gif'
BACKGROUND_IMAGE = 'Background.gif'

# Speed
MOVE_SPEED = 10

# Movement
def forward():
    turtle.forward(MOVE_SPEED)
    screen.update()

def backward():
    turtle.backward(MOVE_SPEED)
    screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Monkey by Anders")
screen.bgpic(BACKGROUND_IMAGE)
screen.bgcolor("dark green")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

screen.addshape(MONKEY_IMAGE)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape(MONKEY_IMAGE)
turtle.penup()

# Position
turtle.backward(325)
turtle.left(90)
screen.update()

# Keyboard
screen.onkey(forward, 'Up')
screen.onkey(backward, 'Down')
screen.listen()

# Main game loop
screen.mainloop()
```